# How to reinstall things on freebsd

Tags: freebsd, reinstall

I was installing wget like so:

```
# cd /usr/ports/ftp/wget
# make install clean
```

And then the interface popped up asking for build options.

I made a mistake in build options

```
# make install clean
===>  wget-1.13.4_1 GNUTLS and OPENSSL are mutually exclusive, enable at most one of them.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/ftp/wget.
```

How can I go back to edit the build options? When I try to rebuild `make install clean` or `make install` it keeps coming back to `Error code 1`.

Comment: Have you tried an uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either...

- `make rmconfig` to remove the saved configuration so you can start over; or
- `make config` to open the configuration menu again (prefilled with the build options you have already selected) so you can deselect one of the mutually exclusive options.

Source: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html#AEN7436